# ui-router not changing url in address bar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

When I click the emails button it should load the emails page and change the url to `/emails`.
When I click the texts button it should load the texts page and change the url to `/texts`.

What is actually happening though the email works fine, but when I click on the texts button the correct ctrl and view is loaded and works BUT my address bar keeps the last url I was on instead of changing to the text url.

My application works fine, but I have no idea what is causing this.

When I enter the url manually and hit enter the correct view and ctrl are loaded as expected, but when I click another link and then click the texts link my address bar has the last url still in it.

GOOD
[image]

The URL is wrong it should have `/texts`.
[image]

#### Email Module Code

/emails/emails.js

```
angular.module('rmc.contact.emails', [
    'rmc.contact.emails.create',
    'rmc.contact.emails.edit',
    'rmc.contact.emails.preview',
    'rmc.contact.emails.view'
])

    .config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('rmc.contact.emails', {
                url: '/emails',
                controller: 'EmailsCtrl',
                templateUrl: '/apps/rmc/contact/emails/emails.tpl.html'
            });
    }])
```

/emails/create/create.js

```
angular.module('rmc.contact.emails.create', [])

    .config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('rmc.contact.emails.create', {
                url: '/create?cardId',
                controller: 'EmailsCreateCtrl',
                templateUrl: '/apps/rmc/contact/emails/create/create.tpl.html'
            });
    }])
```

#### Text Module Code

/contact/texts/texts.js

```
angular.module('rmc.contact.texts', [
    'rmc.contact.texts.create',
    'rmc.contact.texts.edit',
    'rmc.contact.texts.preview',
    'rmc.contact.texts.view'
])

    .config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('rmc.contact.texts', {
                url: '/texts',
                controller: 'TextsCtrl',
                templateUrl: '/apps/rmc/contact/texts/texts.tpl.html'
            });
    }])
```

/contact/texts/create/create.js

```
angular.module('rmc.contact.texts.create', [])

    .config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('rmc.contact.texts.create', {
                url: '/create',
                controller: 'TextsCreateCtrl',
                templateUrl: '/apps/rmc/contact/texts/create/create.tpl.html'
            });
    }])
```

The menu links

/contact/contact.tpl.html

```
    <div class='three-full-btns'>
        <a ui-sref='rmc.contact.calls.create({ cardId: 0 })' ng-if="hasPermission('rmc.calls')" title='Calls' class='btn'>
            <i class='icon-phone'></i>
        </a>

        <a ui-sref='rmc.contact.emails.create({ cardId: 0 })' ng-if="hasPermission('rmc.emails')" title='Emails' class='btn'>
            <i class='icon-envelope'></i>
        </a>

        <a ui-sref='rmc.contact.texts.create' ng-if="hasPermission('rmc.texts')" title='Texts' class='btn'>
            <i class='icon-mobile-phone'></i>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class='three-full-btns'>
        <a ui-sref='rmc.contact.systems.create({ cardId: 0 })' title='Systems' ng-if="hasPermission('rmc.systems')" class='btn'>
            <i class='icon-ok'></i>
        </a>

        <a ui-sref='rmc.contact.forms.create({ cardId: "" })' ng-if="hasPermission('rmc.forms')" title='Forms' class='btn'>
            <i class='icon-file-text'></i>
        </a>

        <a ui-sref='rmc.contact.columns.view({ cardId: "" })' ng-if="hasPermission('rmc.columns')" title='Column Forms' class='btn'>
            <i class='icon-columns'></i>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you consider update the version of `ui-router`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in your controllers for a `$state.go()` that is sending you to the state you're already in immediately after the state loads. Doing this will cause the behavior you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should explicity declare params in text route, otherwise ui-router does NOT view the param

```
 url: '/texts?cardId'
```

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#important-stateparams-gotcha

Comment: I removed the cardId from the ui-sref, didn't actually need it but I'm still getting this issue.

Comment: ok, so you should remove the parenthesis probably <a ui-sref='rmc.contact.texts.create'

Comment: Just did but no change, not sure how to replicate this either :/

Comment: just to give it a try, could you add this options: <a ui-sref='rmc.contact.texts.create' **ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}"**

Comment: I got the same behavior

Answer (score 0):

May be problem here:

```
<a ui-sref='rmc.contact.texts.create({ cardId: 0 })'

...

url: '/create',
```

You missed ?cardId

Comment: I removed the `{ cardId: 0 }` but still getting that issue.